# The specified node cannot be inserted as the valid child of this node, because the specified node is the wrong type

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am dynamically building the xml through C# code and I get this error

> "The specified node cannot be inserted as the valid child of this
>   node, because the specified node is the wrong"

This is my main class

```
internal class  Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateXml xml = new CreateXml();
            xml.multipleXML();
        }
    }
```

I have commented as “ERROR” below where i am getting run time exception. Please help how to fix this error.

My Xml Class is here.

```
internal class CreateXml
    {

        private XmlDocument HandlingXmlDoc;
        private String baseHandlingXML = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><SHandling><BLocation><SLocation><Identifier>02898</Identifier></SLocation></BLocation><Context><UserName>0289800001</UserName><Application>STOCK</Application></Context><Counting><SubmissionDateTime>2014-04-02T16:38:48.9345238+01:00</SubmissionDateTime><ProcessImmediately>YES</ProcessImmediately><Counts><Count><ProductIdentifier>050025488</ProductIdentifier><CountDateTime>2014-04-02T16:38:49.366567+01:00</CountDateTime><LocationCounts></LocationCounts></Count></Counts></Counting></SHandling>";
        private XmlDocument locCountXmlDocument;
        private String baseLocCountXML = "<LocationCount><Name>Bangalore</Name><SCounts><SCount><Quantity>1</Quantity><UnitOfMeasure>CASES</UnitOfMeasure></SCount><SCount><Quantity>1</Quantity><UnitOfMeasure>SINGLES</UnitOfMeasure></SCount></SCounts></LocationCount>";

        public CreateXml()
        {
            Initialise();
        }

        public String GetStockHandlingXmlString { get { return HandlingXmlDoc.OuterXml; } }
        public XmlDocument GetStockHandlingXmlDocument { get { return HandlingXmlDoc; } }

        private void Initialise()
        {
            HandlingXmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            HandlingXmlDoc.LoadXml(baseHandlingXML);

            locCountXmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
            locCountXmlDocument.LoadXml(baseLocCountXML);
        }

        public void multipleXML()
        {
            XmlNode countNode = HandlingXmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "Count", null);

            XmlNode productIdentifierNode = HandlingXmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "ProductIdentifier", null);
            productIdentifierNode.InnerText = "123345";

            XmlNode countDateTimeNode = HandlingXmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "CountDateTime", null);
            countDateTimeNode.InnerText = DateTime.Now.ToString();

            //XmlNode locationCountNode = HandlingXmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "LocationCounts", null);

            countNode.AppendChild(productIdentifierNode);
            countNode.AppendChild(countDateTimeNode);
            countNode.AppendChild(SetNewLocation("Bangalore","30","30"));//ERROR

            HandlingXmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//SHandling//Counting//Counts").AppendChild(countNode);


        }

        private XmlNode SetNewLocation(String location, String casesQuantity, String singlesQuantity)
        {
            XmlDocument docCountXml = new XmlDocument();
            docCountXml.LoadXml(baseLocCountXML);

            SetValue(docCountXml, "LocationCount/Name", location);

            var xmlNodeList = docCountXml.SelectNodes("LocationCount/SCounts/SCount/Quantity");
            xmlNodeList[0].FirstChild.Value = casesQuantity;
            xmlNodeList[1].FirstChild.Value = singlesQuantity;

            return docCountXml.SelectSingleNode("/");
        }
        private static void SetValue(XmlDocument xmlDocument, String key, String value)
        {
            var xmlNode = xmlDocument.SelectSingleNode(key);
            xmlNode.FirstChild.Value = value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: har07  please find the line below which is throwing the error. countNode.AppendChild(SetNewLocation("Bangalore","30","30"));//ERROR

Comment: That's because `SetNewLocation()` method returns `XmlDocument` when the expected type is `XmlElement`. But I can't tell how to fix it unless you can explain what is that method supposed to do.

Comment: @har07 but the return type of the method is XMLNode and when i eventually AppendChild with xmlNode it should not give me any error. let me know if i am wrong?... This method has to build an xml like                                                       `<LocationCount>
 <Name>Bangalore</Name>
 <SCounts>
  <SCount>
   <Quantity>1</Quantity>
   <UnitOfMeasure>CASES</UnitOfMeasure>
  </SCount>
  <SCount>
   <Quantity>1</Quantity>
   <UnitOfMeasure>SINGLES</UnitOfMeasure>
  </SCount>
 </SCounts>
</LocationCount>

Comment: Both XmlDocument and XmlElement are descendant of XmlNode. You can avoid that error by changing this part : `docCountXml.SelectSingleNode("/");` to become  : `docCountXml.DocumentElement;`, but then you'll discover another problem : **you can't append XmlNode created from different XmlDocument instance**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are inserting an external xmlnode from different xml.

my edit is here, I use a workaround to load the xmlnode in the new document and then append it to your node

```
countNode.AppendChild(countNode.OwnerDocument.ImportNode(test, true));
```

try this solution

```
public void multipleXML()
        {
            XmlNode countNode = HandlingXmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "Count", null);

            XmlNode productIdentifierNode = HandlingXmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "ProductIdentifier", null);
            productIdentifierNode.InnerText = "123345";

            XmlNode countDateTimeNode = HandlingXmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "CountDateTime", null);
            countDateTimeNode.InnerText = DateTime.Now.ToString();

            //XmlNode locationCountNode = HandlingXmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "LocationCounts", null);

            countNode.AppendChild(productIdentifierNode);
            countNode.AppendChild(countDateTimeNode);
            var test = SetNewLocation("Bangalore", "30", "30");
            countNode.AppendChild(countNode.OwnerDocument.ImportNode(test, true));

            //countNode.AppendChild(test);//ERROR

            HandlingXmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//SHandling//Counting//Counts").AppendChild(countNode);


        }
```

and another edit in SetNewLocation function

(my edit `return docCountXml.SelectSingleNode("LocationCount");`)

```
 private XmlNode SetNewLocation(String location, String casesQuantity, String singlesQuantity)
        {
            XmlDocument docCountXml = new XmlDocument();
            docCountXml.LoadXml(baseLocCountXML);

            SetValue(docCountXml, "LocationCount/Name", location);

            var xmlNodeList = docCountXml.SelectNodes("LocationCount/SCounts/SCount/Quantity");
            xmlNodeList[0].FirstChild.Value = casesQuantity;
            xmlNodeList[1].FirstChild.Value = singlesQuantity;

            return docCountXml.SelectSingleNode("LocationCount");
        }
```

for references [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fa8a4719-9e5d-4e98-b90f-f36d9a89d069/appending-an-xmlchildnode-from-one-xml-to-another-xml-file?forum=xmlandnetfx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.ownerdocument.aspx)

Comment: your answer is perfect faby. Thank You Very much